# Picks multiple parts of string line

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I am a new to shell script. This is just a variation of some previous questions, but I still cannot find answers. I have the following txt file (one line and no space):

```
;100=Raspberry;101=Apple;102=Orange;103=Kiwi;104=grape;
```

I like to pick anything with `101=*` or `103=*` as an output. So the output needs to look like the following:

```
;101=Apple;103=Kiwi
```

I was trying to write a command by modifying

```
grep -o -m 1 ';101=.*;\|;103=.*' file.txt
```

But it picks everything after `101=.*`. I know that's what the commands says, but still not sure how to change it. I am using Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` tries to match as many characters as possible, that's why you get the rest of the line. So instead of `.` (any char) you have to use `[^;]` (any char except the semicolon):

```
grep -o ';101=[^;]*\|;103=[^;]*'
```

I'm not sure what to tried to achieve with `-m 1` in a one-liner. Anyhow you need to combine your output in one line to get the desired result. But I bet you can find out how to do it yourself (in the end it's your exercise, not ours).

Answer (score 0):

I have used below awk command to achieve the same

```
 awk -F ";" '{print ";"$3";"$5}' filename
```

output

```
;101=Apple;103=Kiwi
```